# collision detection in canvas html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have this collision detection function but it's not working for me .
When the circle hit the bar it should be place at the bottom of the bar and the game end. 
Here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/QnBhK/3/

as you can see a problem is occurring and the ball is stuck in the air instead of the bottom of the bar and i think that the function is not working properly

```
 function collides(rx, ry, rw, rh, cx, cy, cradius) {
            var x = Math.abs(cx - rx);
            var y = Math.abs(cy - ry);
            if (x > rw / 2 + cradius) { return (false); };
            if (y > rh / 2 + cradius) { return (false); };
            if (x <= rw / 2) { return (true); };
            if (y <= rh / 2) { return (true); };
            var dx = x - rw / 2;
            var dy = y - rh / 2
            return (dx * dx + dy * dy <= cradius * cradius);
        }
```

Comment: When I ran this test, the ball was at the bottom of the page and jumped up and back down when I hit the space bar.  What browser are you using?  I'm using FF

Comment: yes that the objective of the game : you should hit the bar when you hit one of the bars the ball should be place in the bottom of the bar that u have hit

Comment: Ouch!  I posted the code you're using very late last night and it had a typo and an omission due to my tiredness.  Fixed now...Very sorry!  Please see the original post for the fixed answer (again, sorry): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885297/collision-detection-in-html5-canvas/20887488#20887488

Comment: thank you so much for this wonderful answer