# canvas x y coordinate detection

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a mini-game and cant seem to be able to get my player to move around the green square but not go through it. When i try my current code the character can move near it but not got passed the x, y coordinates of the green square. Please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    #canvas{
      background-color: black; 
    }
  </style>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="300px" width="300px"/>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var px = 100;
var py = 100;
var pw = 10;
var ph = 10;
var ex = 10;
var ey = 10;
var ew = 10;
var eh = 10;

window.addEventListener("keydown", moveChar);
window.addEventListener("keyup", moveChar);
window.addEventListener("keypress", moveChar);


//frames update
setInterval(function(){
 draw();
 collision();
}, 1);
function draw(){
 //clears junk
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 //draws player
 context.fillStyle = "red";
 context.fillRect(px, py, pw, ph);
 context.fill();
 context.fillStyle = "green";
 context.fillRect(ex, ey, ew, eh);
 context.fill();
}
function collision(){
 if(px < ex + ew && px + pw > ex){
  px++;
 }
 if(py < ey + eh && ph + py > ey){
  py++;
 }
}
function moveChar(){
 var k = event.which || event.keyCode;

 if(k == 37){
  px -= 1;
 }
 if(k == 38){
  py -= 1;
 }
 if(k == 39){
  px += 1;
 }
 if(k == 40){
  py += 1;
 }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps look at this answer regarding 2D shape [collision detection in html5 canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20887488/648350)

Answer (score 2):

What is your collision code intending to do? when you move the character up you do px - 1 but when it meets the if condition you do px + 1. You are subtracting one and then adding one straight away.

Comment: I want the red square to move around the green square but not go through it. When i add to px and py its detect the collision between the two and then add one to that so it dosent go through the green square. The problem is the invisible border generated by my if statement. I cant figure that out

Comment: ok so I've quickly add some functions that do, I believe, what you want or part of it... there would be more cases to be covered but this should be a starting point. I tried to extract every step into functions with long names that tell you what they do. Hope this helps. 

[jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/goraxeg/2/edit?html,js,output)